# Button command(s) to select next / previous item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, command

Is there a simple command i can send to a standard WPF ListBox using a Button that will get it to select the next / previous item in the list?

Currently I'm rolling with this solution:

```
            <Button Width="30" Height="30" x:Name="PreviousButton">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction Increment="True"
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedIndex"
                                                 TargetName="MyListBox"
                                                 Value="-1" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
           <!-- ListBox would be here. -->
           <Button Width="30" Height="30" x:Name="NextButton">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction Increment="True"
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedIndex"
                                                 TargetName="MyListBox"
                                                 Value="1" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
```

Which is fine. It does cause an exception if you hit the previous button when you're on the first item on the list (same with last), but the current plan is to tell it to disable the button if the selectedindex is the first/last item in the list.

I'm asking this question just to see if I'm missing a trick more than anything. "No, that's not possible, you have to do it this other way" is a perfectly acceptable answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mvvm would nice and Simpler. This is how i will solve it.Note my sample code uses mvvmLight toolkit.

View

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverFlow1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlow1"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:StackOverFlow1.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" x:Name="ListBox"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Next" Width="50" Height="24" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox,Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
            <Button Content="Previous" Width="50" Height="24" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox,Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace StackOverFlow1.ViewModel
{

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
         NextCommand=new RelayCommand<int>(OnNext,CanNext);
         PreviousCommand=new RelayCommand<int>(OnPrevious,CanPrevious);
            SelectedIndex = 0;

            foreach (var student in GetStudent())
            {
                _students.Add(student);
            }
        }

        public ICommand NextCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PreviousCommand { get; set; }
        private int _selectedIndex;


        private List<Student> GetStudent()
        {
            return new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame0"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame1"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame2"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame3"},
                  new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame4"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame5"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame6"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame7"},
                   new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame8"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame9"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame10"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame11"},
                  new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame12"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame13"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame14"},
                 new Student {Id = 0,Name = "Kwame15"},
            };
        }
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set { _selectedIndex = value;RaisePropertyChanged(()=>SelectedIndex); }
        }


        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students=new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get { return _students; }
            set { _students = value; }
        }


        private void OnNext(int index)
        {
            if (SelectedIndex != Students.Count)
                SelectedIndex += 1;
            else
            {
                SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private bool CanNext(int indext)
        {
            return SelectedIndex != Students.Count;
        }

        private void OnPrevious(int index)
        {
            if (SelectedIndex != 0)
                SelectedIndex -= 1;
            else
            {
                SelectedIndex = Students.Count;
            }
        }

        private bool CanPrevious(int index)
        {
            return SelectedIndex != 0;
        }

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Id}-{Name}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want the solution file or further explanation please email me suulisindiyaka@stoicteam.com

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" command for it, just create NextItemCommand and PrevItemCommand that will change `int value;`, wich you can bind to `ListBox.SelectedIndex` and this will be that you want. About enable\disable buttons just pass an Enabled method for each command so it will check, that `value` can be changed.